# Add an Existing Animated GIF into a Still Image Without Losing the Animation

Tags: gimp, animation, animated-gif

Using [gimp](https://www.gimp.org/), I'd like to insert an animate gif into another still image without losing the animation. Is there an easy way to accomplish this in GIMP?

I was able to drag the animated image's layer-group over into the still image, but after doing so (even though that newly added layer-group shows as the top layer within gimp's layering tool) I cannot see any changes to the destination image.

Comment: You can't have an animated GIF inside a still image. That would be impossible.  But you could have a still image on every frame layer of a GIF animation.  I think there's a script that can do this, although I can't remember its name. Also pretty sure it's been mentioned here already on GDSE, I just can't find it right now.

Comment: I've found a script here that could do it: https://chiselapp.com/user/saulgoode/repository/script-fu/wiki?name=sg-combine-bg I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: I understand that the end result would have to be an animated image, and not a still image, but I was hoping that Gimp would understand that if a user pastes an animate gif into a still image, it should convert that still image into an animate image. I guess that would be too easy.

Comment: LOL - unfortunately applications don't "understand" things. They are just dumb tools. They can only do what you tell them to do.  Yeah, you guessed right - that would be too easy!!!

Comment: Forgive my personification.  I was hoping that the developers of Gimp would have anticipated a user inserting an animated image into another image with the desired outcome of producing an animated image that combines the source and destination images without losing animation. Perhaps, I was born 100 years too early and this level of anticipation can only be expected after Gimp version 75. Or maybe, I'm just inherently too hopeful.

Comment: The "core" Gimp developers are under 10 people, none of them doing it as his/her day job.... Let them focus on the hard stuff. Gimp is very easy to script and can also be extended by plugins, so many problems have solutions as Gimp add-ons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it, you have to merge every frame of the animation over as any copies of the still image. Pretty tedious but there are scripts that will do this for you, see for instance [`ofn-interleave-layers`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/)(you want the "single layer under stack" option, see the HTML doc included in the ZIP).

Comment: I wonder if you have you ever been able to get GAP to work in 2.10.x - because that could also be a solution to automation in animated projects. I know it works in 2.8 (kind of). It's a shame GAP hasn't been updated since 2012

Comment: Didn't even try. I prefer to write my own scripts :)